# How do I run sample Android SDK apps in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, sample

I have gone to `File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code` but when I select the folder (Am I supposed to select the whole folder?) and attempt to run it in the emulator that I set up, nothing happens in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

File->New->Other->Android->Android Sample Project and then press next

Now,

you have to select Build Target and press next You will get list of android sample apps select and press finish

Good Luck.....

Answer (score 0):

Try :

File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace

Good luck,
Peter